# Showing that two operations on a set that are homomorphism of each other are equal

Tags: group-theory

I'm having a hard time understanding what I have to do in this problem.

Let $M$ be a set equipped with two monoid structures $(\cdot_i,e_i)$, $i=1,2$, where
$$ \cdot_i : M \times M \rightarrow M $$

is the binary (associative) operation and $e_i$ the identity element. Assume that $\cdot_1$ and $\cdot_2$ are homomorphisms of each other. Then prove that $\cdot_1 = \cdot_2$ and the resulting operation is abelian.

I know what a Monoid is and also what a homomorphism between two monoid structures is. But in this case, what exactly does it mean to say the two operations are homomorphism of each other, I'm a bit confused about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: It looks strange indeed. Where does it come from? Maybe it means $\cdot_1$ is a monoid homomorphism from the direct product $(M_2\times M_2,\cdot_2\times\cdot_2)$ to $(M_2,\cdot_2)$ and vice-versa (exchanging 1 and 2)?

Comment: It's part of a problem set from a Homework Assignment and I have no idea how to approach the problem

Comment: If it is a homework assignment, then ask for clarification from your instructor on the meaning of "are homomorphisms of each other."